# Login in a different Router -ReactJs-

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

My AppRouter is wrapped in a navigation bar (Drawer, like a control panel) from `material-ui` library.

```
<NavigationBar>
    <AppRouter/>
 </NavigationBar>
```

And my AppRouter:

```
<Switch>
    <PublicRoute path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/Edit" component={EditPage} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/Delete" component={DeletePage} />
 </Switch>
```

Since my AppRouter it's wrapped inside the navigation bar how can I make my Login Page SEPARATED from the rest of the pages? I want first to LogIn in a page and then redirect in a SPA with a Dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

```
<NavigationBar>
  { isAuthenticated && <AppRouter/> }
  { !isAuthenticated && <PublicRouter/> }
</NavigationBar>
```

You can keep an isAuthenticated flag to render two different switch component. Approuter -

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/Edit" component={EditPage} />
  <Route path="/Delete" component={DeletePage} />
</Switch>
```

Similarly a PublicRouter can be defined which can have login Route.